# Convert to gradle-kotlin-dsl Jfrog.Artifactory config

Tags: gradle, kotlin, artifactory, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to migrate from groovy to gradle-kotlin dsl, but I'm new to it, so I dont know how to configure Jfrog Artifactory. Please help me with converting that part of code to gradle-kotlin dsl:

```
task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.allJava
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "http://10.0.0.49:8081/artifactory"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'gradle-dev-local'
            username = artifactory_username
            password = artifactory_password
        }
        defaults {
            publications('mavenJava')
            publishArtifacts = true
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
}



publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = "ua.tiras.oloader"
            artifactId = 'core'
            version = "1.0.62"
            artifact("$buildDir/libs/${project.getName()}.jar")
            artifact sourceJar {
                classifier "sources"
            }
            pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.api.allDependencies.each { dependency ->
                    def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', dependency.group)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', dependency.name)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('version', dependency.version)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
val sourcesJar by tasks.creating(Jar::class) {
    dependsOn(JavaPlugin.CLASSES_TASK_NAME)
    classifier = "sources"
    from(sourceSets["main"].allSource)
}

publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("mavenJava") {
            groupId = "ua.tiras"
            artifactId = "aloader-core"
            version = "0.0.4"

            artifact(sourcesJar)
            artifact("$buildDir/libs/${project.name}.jar")

            pom {
                withXml {
                    asNode().appendNode("dependencies").let {
                        for (dependency in configurations["api"].dependencies) {
                            it.appendNode("dependency").apply {
                                appendNode("groupId", dependency.group)
                                appendNode("artifactId", dependency.name)
                                appendNode("version", dependency.version)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    setContextUrl("http://dev.tirascloud.com:8081/artifactory")
    publish(delegateClosureOf<PublisherConfig> {
        repository(delegateClosureOf<GroovyObject> {
            setProperty("repoKey", "gradle-dev-local")
            setProperty("username", project.findProperty("artifactory_username") ?: "nouser")
            setProperty("password", project.findProperty("artifactory_password") ?: "nopass")
        })
        defaults(delegateClosureOf<GroovyObject> {
            invokeMethod("publications", "mavenJava")
            setProperty("publishPom", true)
            setProperty("publishArtifacts", true)
        })
    })
    resolve(delegateClosureOf<ResolverConfig> {
        setProperty("repoKey", "repo")
    })
```

Comment: Is it just me that I don't see "jfrog" anywhere in the suggestions.

Comment: @eelghEEz Artifactory is made by JFrog. It doesn't just refer to OJO (oss.jfrog.org) which is itself an instance of JFrog's Artifactory product. The artifactory plugin works for any Artifactory instance.

Comment: Better / newer answers below - require much less code :-)

Answer (score 4):

I found another example - an official one JFrog:

https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/gradle-examples/gradle-kts-example-publish/build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
import org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.ArtifactoryTask

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jfrog.buildinfo", "build-info-extractor-gradle", "4.+")
    }
    configurations.classpath {
        resolutionStrategy {
            cacheDynamicVersionsFor(0, "seconds")
            cacheChangingModulesFor(0, "seconds")
        }
    }
}

plugins {
    java
    `maven-publish`
}

fun javaProjects() = subprojects.filter {
    File(it.projectDir, "src").isDirectory
}

val currentVersion: String by project

allprojects {
    apply(plugin = "com.jfrog.artifactory")

    group = "org.jfrog.test.gradle.publish"
    version = currentVersion
    status = "Integration"

    repositories {
        maven("http://127.0.0.1:8081/artifactory/libs-release")
    }
}

tasks.named<ArtifactoryTask>("artifactoryPublish") {
    skip = true
}

project("services") {
    tasks.named<ArtifactoryTask>("artifactoryPublish") {
        skip = true
    }
}

configure(javaProjects()) {
    apply(plugin = "java")
    apply(plugin = "maven-publish")

    dependencies {
        testImplementation("junit:junit:4.7")
    }

    configure<PublishingExtension> {
        publications {
            register<MavenPublication>("mavenJava") {
                from(components.getByName("java"))
                artifact(file("$rootDir/gradle.properties"))
            }
        }
    }
}

project("api") {
    apply(plugin = "ivy-publish")

    configure<PublishingExtension> {
        publications {
            register<IvyPublication>("ivyJava") {
                from(components.getByName("java"))

                artifact(file("$rootDir/settings.gradle.kts")) {
                    name = "gradle-settings"
                    extension = "txt"
                    type = "text"
                }
                // The config below will add a extra attribute to the ivy.xml
                // See http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/concept.html#extra
                descriptor.withXml {
                    val info = asNode().get("info") as groovy.util.NodeList
                    val first = info.first() as groovy.util.Node
                    first.attributes()["e:architecture"] = "amd64"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    tasks.named<ArtifactoryTask>("artifactoryPublish") {
        publications(publishing.publications["ivyJava"])
    }
}

configure<org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.dsl.ArtifactoryPluginConvention> {
    clientConfig.isIncludeEnvVars = true

    setContextUrl("http://127.0.0.1:8081/artifactory")
    publish {
        repository {
            setRepoKey("libs-snapshot-local") // The Artifactory repository key to publish to
            setUsername(findProperty("artifactory_user")) // The publisher user name
            setPassword(findProperty("artifactory_password")) // The publisher password
            // This is an optional section for configuring Ivy publication (when publishIvy = true).
            ivy {
                setIvyLayout("[organization]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml")
                setArtifactLayout("[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]")
                setMavenCompatible(true) // Convert any dots in an [organization] layout value to path separators, similar to Maven"s groupId-to-path conversion. True if not specified
            }
        }

        defaults {
            // Reference to Gradle publications defined in the build script.
            // This is how we tell the Artifactory Plugin which artifacts should be
            // published to Artifactory.
            publications("mavenJava")
            setPublishArtifacts(true)
            // Properties to be attached to the published artifacts.
            setProperties(mapOf(
                "qa.level" to "basic",
                "dev.team" to "core"
            ))
            setPublishPom(true) // Publish generated POM files to Artifactory (true by default)
            setPublishIvy(true) // Publish generated Ivy descriptor files to Artifactory (true by default)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't work for me with the artifactory plugin version `4.27.1`. A good place to check is definitely the already mentioned [provided example by JFrog](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/gradle-examples/gradle-kts-example-publish/build.gradle.kts). Here is a simplified extract based on the offical example:

```
configure<org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.dsl.ArtifactoryPluginConvention> {
    clientConfig.isIncludeEnvVars = true

    setContextUrl(findProperty("artifactory_url"))
    publish {
        repository {
            setRepoKey(repoKeyValue) // The Artifactory repository key to publish to
            setUsername(findProperty("artifactory_user")) // The publisher user name
            setPassword(findProperty("artifactory_password")) // The publisher password
            setMavenCompatible(true)
        }

        defaults {
            publications("mypublicationreference")
            setPublishArtifacts(true)            
        }
    }
}

configure<PublishingExtension> {
    publications {
        register<MavenPublication>("mypublicationreference") {
            from(components.getByName("java"))
            artifact("$buildDir/libs/${project.name}.jar")
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the referenced properties such as `artifactory_url` can be defined in a `gradle.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify accepted answer this way.

```
plugins {
    id("com.jfrog.artifactory") version "4.32.0"
}

repositories {
    maven("https://jcenter.bintray.com/")
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

// If you set these values in gradle.properties

val artifactoryContextUrl: String by project
val artifactoryUser: String by project
val artifactoryPassword: String by project

artifactory {
    setContextUrl(artifactoryContextUrl)
    publish {
        repository {
            setProperty("repoKey", "gradle-dev-local")
            setProperty("username", artifactoryUser)
            setProperty("password", artifactoryPassword)
        }
        defaults {
            invokeMethod("publications", "mavenJava")
            setProperty("publishPom", true)
            setProperty("publishArtifacts", true)
        }
    }
    resolve {
        setProperty("repoKey", "repo")
    }
}
```